# Cannot find module 'd3-selection', 'd3-shape', 'd3-scale'

Tags: angular, d3.js

In the Angular2 app, in app.component.ts I have the following imports: 
`import * as d3 from 'd3-selection';
import * as d3Scale from 'd3-scale';
import * as d3Shape from 'd3-shape';`

And I installed d3 by doing npm install d3. My package.json has `"d3": "^4.10.2",` int the dependencies.

By looking into some of the questions here, there was one which used Angular-Seed, so there was some file seed.config.ts in `/tools/config/seed.config.ts` but since I am using `ng new my-app` I have no such file.

I also installed typings and then did `typings install d3 --save`.

This didn't work either.

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from a fresh project I can guarantee this will work:

`npm install --save d3`

`npm install --save-dev @types/d3`

Then in your component it's as simple as including at the top of your file:

`import * as d3 from 'd3';`

You can then use *any* d3 method in your typescript methods:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    d3.select("body").style("background-color", "black");
    console.log(d3.scaleLinear());
  }
```

Feel free to clone [this working github repo](https://github.com/zbagley/angular-d3-example) as an example of implementing d3 into your project.

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked! You finally put an end to hours of helplessness. A question but. Will this work in the same fashion for dc.js ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure dc.js since has a dependency on `crossfilter` and I've never used it myself. You may need to install that separately, but @types/dc exists, so it _should_ be just as simple for dc.js

Comment: @user33760 This answer has a working github repo using AngularCLI v1.3.1 and D3 v4.10.2. Pretty sure 1.2.8 works with D3v4 as well.

Comment: @SahilBabbar Event handling is best done through the Angular Framework. If you need to add an event you will either want to add the click event in the html template or by targeting the element as a ViewChild.

Comment: @Z.Bagley D3's event is different than `window` event. So, in some cases you may required D3's event specifically, like for drag-drop.

Comment: @SahilBabbar Drag events are definitely included: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-drag/index.d.ts